# Simple Objective-C program for reading from SQLite manager database

Tags: objective-c, macos, sqlite

I'm new to Objective C. Please suggest me a program to read data from SQLite Manager Database. I'm using Xcode 6.6.1, Mac 10.10.2 and SQLite Manager. Kindly assist.

Comment: Duplicate of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337859/read-data-from-sqlite-manager-database-using-objective-c). Please do not repost the same question.

Comment: The "duplicate" link is dead - and I wish for the answers... what now?

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no simple program when it comes to sqlite; Different components combine to read/write/delete/update data from sqlite.

- I would recommend [Ray Wenderlich
  Sqlite tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app).
- Here is a super easy third party [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Comment: @Rob Well dude If I wanted to copy someone's answer, I would have given link to some other tutorial at least. I wrote it myself, you don't have to believe me. Moreover I didn't see the duplicate question, not until you gave me the link.